# How can I detect in Kotlin or Java whether the Android device supports MHL (HDMI)?

Tags: android, feature-detection, hdmi

Some Android devices support HDMI via micro USB or USB C cables and adapters. Usually using [MHL (Mobile High-Definition Link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link)

How can I check programmatically from my app whether the device it's running on supports MHL?